# Why my web page didn't show at my WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I can't speak english correctly, excuse me, but can somebody help me?
I want to show my company web page with a web view, i enter a url of my company website to my Activity and using loadUrl() to load, but when i running my project it never show the web page. Why it happen? i enter a url at the browser and it work, but with web view it not work. Please help me

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.ithits.hits;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
private String webUrl = "https://hits.hokimtong.org/";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(webUrl);
        Log.e("tag", "Url Loading " + webUrl");
    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ithits.hits">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: Please only use the android-studio tag if your questions referring to the IDE Android-Studio.

Comment: try removing all settings: webView.getSettings() and Also remove WebViewClient. If that works then add each setting as needed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for any suggetion, it very help me

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved thankyou everyone for your help, the problem in my device OS version, it's too old, and i have to buy another device to running my project